# How can I defer or async this JS script code?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, deferred, document.write

I have a problem with this code. I know that we can add async or defer for external scripts, but with this script I can't handle with the `document.write("<script src=\"http://example......` , so when I add defer or async to that code the script stop working. Can anyone help me because this code made some render blocking problem with my blog.

This is the code:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
var numposts = 5;
var showpostthumbnails = true;
var showpostdate = false;</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// Recent Post By Tag
// Recent Post By Tag For Blogger
function rcentbytag(e){document.write('<ul class="recent-by-tag">');for(var t=0;t<numposts;t++){var n=e.feed.entry[t];var r=n.title.$t;var i;if(t==e.feed.entry.length)break;for(var o=0;o<n.link.length;o++){if(n.link[o].rel=="replies"&&n.link[o].type=="text/html"){var u=n.link[o].title;var f=n.link[o].href}if(n.link[o].rel=="alternate"){i=n.link[o].href;break}}var l;try{l=n.media$thumbnail.url}catch(h){s=n.content.$t;a=s.indexOf("<img");b=s.indexOf('src="',a);c=s.indexOf('"',b+5);d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-5);if(a!=-1&&b!=-1&&c!=-1&&d!=""){l=d}else l="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-giova1ZCh-A/Uzq6L8QTJNI/AAAAAAAAAJc/USXictTq_xs/s70-c/KM+Icon.png"}var p=n.published.$t;var v=p.substring(0,4);var m=p.substring(5,7);var g=p.substring(8,10);var y=new Array;y[1]="Januari";y[2]="Februari";y[3]="Maret";y[4]="April";y[5]="Mei";y[6]="Juni";y[7]="Juli";y[8]="Agustus";y[9]="September";y[10]="Oktober";y[11]="November";y[12]="Desember";document.write('<li class="clear">');if(showpostthumbnails==true)document.write('<a href="'+i+'" target ="_blank" title="'+r+'"><img class="rct-thumb" alt="'+r+'" src="'+l+'"/></a>');document.write('<strong><a href="'+i+'" target ="_blank" title="'+r+'">'+r+'</a></strong>');document.write('<br>');var x="";var T=0;if(showpostdate==true){x='<span class="showdates">'+x+g+" "+y[parseInt(m,10)]+" "+v+"</span>";T=1}document.write(x);document.write("</li>");if(t!=numposts-1)document.write("")}document.write("</ul>")}
//]]>
</script>

<script>
document.write("<script src=\"http://example.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/LabelHere?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=rcentbytag\"><\/script>");
</script>
```

Thank You ...

Comment: step 1: don't use document.write

Comment: I don't know what can I use instead of it. I'm still learning Javascript . Thank You for your responding.

Comment: Why aren't you just including the `<script>` tag directly rather than `document.writing` it?

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried that, but it doesn't work. I'm using `document.write` because i'm using this script inside posts to print results from any Category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defer` or `async` change the load timing of your scripts and thus will change when your script executes and thus will change the timing of the `document.write()` statements in your `rcentbytag()` function.

Since the `rcentbytag()` function is inserting content into your page with `document.write()`, you can't change the location of that script in the page unless you rewrite it not to use `document.write()` and to insert content into the appropriate place in the page another way (such as `.appendChild()`).

So, if you want to defer the loading of the script that calls `rcentbytag()`, then you will have to rewrite `rcentbytag()` to insert the content it puts into the page a different way that does not use `document.write()`.

You will have a lot more options when you remove all use of `document.write()`.  Besides getting in your way here, it can also slow down the loader for a variety of reasons.

Your script that uses `document.write()` works out to be this when it's decompressed:

```
function rcentbytag(e) {
    document.write('<ul class="recent-by-tag">');
    for (var t = 0; t < numposts; t++) {
        var n = e.feed.entry[t];
        var r = n.title.$t;
        var i;
        if (t == e.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var o = 0; o < n.link.length; o++) {
            if (n.link[o].rel == "replies" && n.link[o].type == "text/html") {
                var u = n.link[o].title;
                var f = n.link[o].href
            }
            if (n.link[o].rel == "alternate") {
                i = n.link[o].href;
                break
            }
        }
        var l;
        try {
            l = n.media$thumbnail.url
        } catch (h) {
            s = n.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf('src="', a);
            c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if (a != -1 && b != -1 && c != -1 && d != "") {
                l = d
            } else l = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-giova1ZCh-A/Uzq6L8QTJNI/AAAAAAAAAJc/USXictTq_xs/s70-c/KM+Icon.png"
        }
        var p = n.published.$t;
        var v = p.substring(0, 4);
        var m = p.substring(5, 7);
        var g = p.substring(8, 10);
        var y = new Array;
        y[1] = "Januari";
        y[2] = "Februari";
        y[3] = "Maret";
        y[4] = "April";
        y[5] = "Mei";
        y[6] = "Juni";
        y[7] = "Juli";
        y[8] = "Agustus";
        y[9] = "September";
        y[10] = "Oktober";
        y[11] = "November";
        y[12] = "Desember";
        document.write('<li class="clear">');
        if (showpostthumbnails == true) document.write('<a href="' + i + '" target ="_blank" title="' + r + '"><img class="rct-thumb" alt="' + r + '" src="' + l + '"/></a>');
        document.write('<strong><a href="' + i + '" target ="_blank" title="' + r + '">' + r + '</a></strong>');
        document.write('<br>');
        var x = "";
        var T = 0;
        if (showpostdate == true) {
            x = '<span class="showdates">' + x + g + " " + y[parseInt(m, 10)] + " " + v + "</span>";
            T = 1
        }
        document.write(x);
        document.write("</li>");
        if (t != numposts - 1) document.write("")
    }
    document.write("</ul>")
}
```

It is possible to replace all the `document.write()` calls in that with a new function that just accumulates the HTML and then insert all that HTML once at the end into a previously placed div in your document:

```
function rcentbytag(e) {
    var storedHTML = "";

    function saveHTML(h) {
        storedHTML += h;
    }

    saveHTML('<ul class="recent-by-tag">');
    for (var t = 0; t < numposts; t++) {
        var n = e.feed.entry[t];
        var r = n.title.$t;
        var i;
        if (t == e.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var o = 0; o < n.link.length; o++) {
            if (n.link[o].rel == "replies" && n.link[o].type == "text/html") {
                var u = n.link[o].title;
                var f = n.link[o].href
            }
            if (n.link[o].rel == "alternate") {
                i = n.link[o].href;
                break
            }
        }
        var l;
        try {
            l = n.media$thumbnail.url
        } catch (h) {
            s = n.content.$t;
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf('src="', a);
            c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if (a != -1 && b != -1 && c != -1 && d != "") {
                l = d
            } else l = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-giova1ZCh-A/Uzq6L8QTJNI/AAAAAAAAAJc/USXictTq_xs/s70-c/KM+Icon.png"
        }
        var p = n.published.$t;
        var v = p.substring(0, 4);
        var m = p.substring(5, 7);
        var g = p.substring(8, 10);
        var y = new Array;
        y[1] = "Januari";
        y[2] = "Februari";
        y[3] = "Maret";
        y[4] = "April";
        y[5] = "Mei";
        y[6] = "Juni";
        y[7] = "Juli";
        y[8] = "Agustus";
        y[9] = "September";
        y[10] = "Oktober";
        y[11] = "November";
        y[12] = "Desember";
        saveHTML('<li class="clear">');
        if (showpostthumbnails == true) saveHTML('<a href="' + i + '" target ="_blank" title="' + r + '"><img class="rct-thumb" alt="' + r + '" src="' + l + '"/></a>');
        saveHTML('<strong><a href="' + i + '" target ="_blank" title="' + r + '">' + r + '</a></strong>');
        saveHTML('<br>');
        var x = "";
        var T = 0;
        if (showpostdate == true) {
            x = '<span class="showdates">' + x + g + " " + y[parseInt(m, 10)] + " " + v + "</span>";
            T = 1
        }
        saveHTML(x);
        saveHTML("</li>");
        if (t != numposts - 1) saveHTML("")
    }
    saveHTML("</ul>")
    document.getElementById("rcentDiv").innerHTML = storedHTML;
}
```

Then, you can change your HTML to this.  This inserts a placeholder `<div>` which is a place for the content to be added and you used the revised `rcentbytag()` that inserts the HTML into that div and then you can use `defer` on the feeds script and it will call `rcentbytag()`which will insert the content appropriately:

```
<div id="rcentDiv"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var numposts = 5;
var showpostthumbnails = true;
var showpostdate = false;

// Recent Post By Tag
// Recent Post By Tag For Blogger
// insert revised rcentbytag() code here
</script>

<script defer src="http://example.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/LabelHere?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=rcentbytag"></script>
```

Comment: So, what you want to say is that I need to build a new code. Am I right? If you can tell me what can I do because I'm not a JS programmer and still a JS learner but need this code, I will appreciate that.  Thank You.

Comment: @AhmedSheta - I wrote a revised `rcentbytag()` function and showed you how to use it in your document so you can use `defer` on the `blogspot.com` script.

Comment: I tried but nothing happened and I get some errors from that code : `<script defer src="http://example.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/LabelHere?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=rcentbytag"></script>` when I pasted it into a blog post on Blogspot Blog.... Also I pasted the revised code as you mentioned in the latest code with `// insert revised rcentbytag() code here` then I tried it in separated `<Script>`, but also nothing happened. I tested it online on W3C Tryit Editor, and also I have nothing. I'm Sorry and I appreciate your efforts with me to solve this problem.

Comment: @AhmedSheta - I'm sure I could help you make this work, but I would need to see the exact page you are trying to see exactly what you have.  Can you either post a link to the page you are trying in a comment here or add the contents of the page to the end of your question so I can see what you have?

Comment: -Go to this page [link](http://www.yes-android.com/2017/04/t113xxs0aqc2-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-lite-7.0-ve-sm-t113.html) ... You will find the old code used inside post under this title (Check the latest Android Devices Specs Datasheets) and also you will find it on the sidebar. This is the results of the old page, so I want the same results but without making any render blocking so I asked about How to defer or async it. Thank You for you help.